# kafka broker and client versions compatibility

Tags: apache-kafka

We are planning to upgrade Kafka broker to 2.12.X but our Kafka clients are still going to use 0.10.x or higher versions

On local, we have verified and not seen any issues in producing and consuming with older client versions mentioned above while the broker is upgraded to kafka_2.12-2.3.0

Is there a compatibility matrix for Kafka broker and client versions mentioned? Did anyone face any issues with such upgrades?

PS -
I went through below link

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compatibility+Matrix

Comment: 2.12 is not a Kafka version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the link says, broker 1.0.0 (and up) will work for basic client interaction on any client that supports features added in KIP-35

The main missing features of clients before 0.11 or 1.0 would be the message headers and idempotent producer or exactly-once processing semantics for Kafka Streams

You'll also want to be careful on upgrading the log format version too soon, because as the Kafka upgrade steps say, you should only change that once most of the clients have upgraded

Comment: sorry, my bad, its Kafka 2.3.0